# Vertical align Glyphicons with text CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm getting an issue in my navbar between my tab and the associated glyphicons.

I would like to align vertically both elements to the center but I don't overcome to do that. I tried some things : `text-align`, `vertical-align` but I think the issue is with my `<li>` and `<div>`elements.

This is my HTML/CSS part :

```css
span.glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<li>
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="{% url 'Homepage' %}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    <div class="navtab"> Accueil </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

I would like to shift glyphicons to the middle of each tab name.

Thank you !

Comment: You applied text-align to `span.glyphicon`, which is of course nonsense - that inline element is only as wide as its content demands it, so that “centering” that content is a fruitless endeavor. You want to apply it to the parent element, so that the (text and inline) content of that element gets centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, text-align: center should be added to the parent element because span is an inline element and does not have a width.

```css
span.glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="{% url 'Homepage' %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
      <div class="navtab"> Accueil </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using flexbox..

```css
span.glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="{% url 'Homepage' %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <div class="navtab"> Accueil </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried your answer which seems to work in your case, but it doesn't work in my script.

Answer (score 1):

`text-align:center` will do the trick:

```css
span.glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="{% url 'Homepage' %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <div class="navtab"> Accueil </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```